# SSIS When viewing query preview some characters are replaced

Tags: sql, ssis, oledb, sybase

I have huge amount of data in Sybase DB and I made OLE DB connector in SSIS where I succesfully connected it. We are using charset = cp1250, because we have data from center europe.

DATABASE: Sybase
Program: Visual Studio 2017 SSIS
Connector: OLE DB

***The Problem:***
when I view some data from my select I can see that it somehow **replaced** , but only two characters (character - ř and character č) with arrow pointing to right. I even set extended properties to: charset=cp1250.
[corrupted data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOSQ4.jpg)

**Does anyone know what to do?** Or hwere to look at? I am completly lost after two days of searching and trying to fix that.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Are you sure the data type of your source column isn't Unicode (nvarchar / nchar)?

Comment: I'd suspect the data type of your output is `DT_STR` and/or the codepage there doesn't match. I'd use `DT_WSTR` instead if possible.

Comment: Also check in the Sybase database via sp_helpsort and confirm the exact sort order and charset which is definitely in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I managed to solve my problem.***

The solution was to **create** new ODBC connector and **replaced** OLE connector. I also have to change some settings. In advance settings, I have change

- Language > **us_english**
- Communication charset > **Client charset**
- client charset > other > **cp1250**

I hope someone it will find usefull :)